# JSON data extraction in swift

Tags: json, swift

I am using the following code:

```
let string = "https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/? 
hasDetails=examples&page=1"
let url = NSURL(string: string)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
request.setValue("KEY", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Mashape-Key")
request.httpMethod = "GET"
let session = URLSession.shared

let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if let resp = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])

        print(json)

    }
}
task.resume()
```

And the following is printed by the 'print(json)' line of code:

```
Optional({
query =     {
    limit = 100;
    page = 1;
};
results =     {
    data =         (
        ".22 caliber",
        ".38 caliber",
        a,
        "a bit",
        "a cappella",
        "a couple of",
        "a few",
        "a great deal",
        "a little",
        "a lot",
        "a posteriori",
        "a priori",
        "a trifle",
        aah,
        abacinate,
        abaft,
        abandon,
        abandoned,
        abandonment,
        abasement,
        abashed,
        "abatable nuisance",
        abate,
        abatement,
        abaxial,
        abbreviated,
        abdicable,
        abdicate,
        abdominal,
        "abdominal breathing",
        abduct,
        aberrant,
        aberrate,
        abhor,
        abhorrent,
        "abide by",
        abiding,
        abject,
        abjectly,
        abjure,
        ablated,
        ablative,
        ablaze,
        able,
        "able-bodied",
        ablutionary,
        abnegate,
        abnegation,
        abnormal,
        abnormally,
        aboard,
        abolish,
        abolition,
        abominable,
        abominably,
        abomination,
        aboral,
        aboriginal,
        abort,
        abortive,
        abound,
        abounding,
        about,
        "about-face",
        above,
        "above all",
        aboveboard,
        aboveground,
        abrasive,
        abreast,
        abridge,
        abridged,
        abroach,
        abroad,
        abrupt,
        abscessed,
        abscond,
        abseil,
        absence,
        absent,
        absently,
        absentminded,
        absolute,
        absolutely,
        absoluteness,
        absolve,
        absolved,
        absorb,
        absorbed,
        absorbent,
        absorptance,
        absorption,
        abstain,
        abstemious,
        abstemiously,
        abstinent,
        abstract,
        abstractive,
        abstruse,
        abstrusely
    );
    total = 21753;
};
})
```

The problem is that I need to get just the data that I want from this i.e. the words.

How do I now get the data from this that I want? i.e. an array of all the words returned (from ".22 caliber" to abstrusely)

Answer (score -1):

I like to use the [SwiftyJson](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftyJSON) cocoapod, as its much easier to read and understand than `JSONDecoder` (but of course, that would work too):

```
import SwiftyJson

let string = "https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/?hasDetails=examples&page=1"
let url = NSURL(string: string)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
request.setValue("KEY", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Mashape-Key")
request.httpMethod = "GET"
let session = URLSession.shared
var wordArray : [String] = []

let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if let resp = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        let json : JSON = JSON(data!)
        for word in json["results"]["data"] { //There's probably a way to cast directly to a [String] here instead but I'm not sure.
            wordArray.append(word)
        }

    }
}
task.resume()
```